# Calculate $\int_0^1f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Calculate $\int_0^1f(x)dx$,where
$$\ f(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    0 & \quad \text{if $x=0$ }\\
    n & \quad \text{if $x\in(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$}
  \end{array} \right.$$

How we can calculate this integral?

Is this simply

$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}ndx=n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}$$?

Comment: I think $n$ is intended to run through all positive integers.

Comment: If $n$ is fixed, then yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(0,1]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$$
so

$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{1/n+1}^{1/n}ndx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n+1}=\infty$$