# Calculate $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Function $f(x)$ is defined as: $f(x) =0$ when $x=0$, and $f(x) = n$ when $x \in (\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$. Calculate $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$.

Assuming that we can safely ignore when $x=0$, then when $x\in (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$, we essentially have

$$1\times\left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)+2\times\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\cdots=\sum_{n \ge 1} n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{1}{n+1}$$

But then the series diverges by integral test. So I am confused.

Comment: looks correct to me

Comment: @user251257 Interesting. The wording of the problem seems to suggest at least the answer is a real number. Perhaps $\infty$ is still a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got: the integral diverges (or, as they say sometimes, ``does not exist'').

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$(0,1]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$$
so
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{1/n+1}^{1/n}ndx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n+1}=\infty$$

From here: [Calculate $\int_0^1f(x)dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984839/calculate-int-01fxdx)